# object from vector with structs

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-address

i 'm pretty new to c++, can you help me with pointers ? i have a struct

```
struct Slice
{
    Slice(): {}
    SliceObj *slObj;
};
```

and vector:

```
std::vector<Slice> slices;
```

So on mouce touch i want to take this object to change his public var:

```
for (vector<Slice>::iterator it = slices.begin(); it != slices.end(); ++it) {

            Slice slice0 = slices[0];
            SliceObj *slObj = slice0.slObj;
            slObj->drag(slObj, x, y);
}
```

[image]

And of coure of course when in drag method i make : slObj->rect.x = x+0.1;, it doesn't make anything good.

Please, help me with this, i can't understand how to carefully get obj with * from another object from vector and then carefully change it's param;
Trouble is in "how to carefully get SliceObj from slice0", not address of var, but this instance.
So here i need to get slObj param, that in future i can make slObj.rect.x = 1;

UPDATE:
when i make slObj->drag method i always see only strange number like:
[image]
but then, when glutPostRedisplay called and it's redraw on method

```
void SliceObj::draw(SliceObj *slObj)
```

then it's all good!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the element through the iterator:

```
for (vector<Slice>::iterator it = slices.begin(); it != slices.end(); ++it) {

        Slice& slice0 = *it //Get the element using iterator (Note the reference, is to avoid copy)
        SliceObj *slObj = slice0.slObj;
        slObj->drag(slObj, x, y);
}
```

However, if you have a C++11 capable compiler, you could simplify things using range-based for loop:

```
for( auto& slObj : slices )
{
    liceObj *slObj = slice0.slObj;
    slObj->drag(slObj, x, y);
}
```

Comment: hm it's interestin, now this error: expected initializer before '&' token

Comment: In which version? C++11 or pre C++11?

Comment: No, all good, but anyway i see only strange numbers, please look in my update

Comment: In SO the way to say an answer was usefull is to upvote it :) If the answer solves your problem, accept it.

Comment: No, you are right! it was only my fault, look, BIIIIG THANKS. please tell me one more advice: why i need Slice &slice = *it; construction ?

Comment: you don't really need it, you coul use the iterator directly dereferencing it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the iterator to get the element from the vector. Here you are always getting the first element. Try this:

```
for (vector<Slice>::iterator it = slices.begin(); it != slices.end(); ++it) {

            Slice slice0 = *it //Get the element using iterator
            SliceObj *slObj = slice0.slObj;
            slObj->drag(slObj, x, y);
}
```

Comment: Sry, i edited my question, trouble not in vector, trouble is in "how to carefully get SliceObj from slice0